# After Effect's Rotoscoping brush algorithms

Tags: ios, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I don't think I'm going to get any replies but here goes: I'm developing an iOS app that performs image segmentation functions. I'm trying to implement the easiest way to crop out a subject from an image without the need of a greenscreen/keying. Most automated solutions like using OpenCV just aren't cutting it.

I've found the rotoscope brush tool in After Effects to be effective at giving hints on where the app should be cutting out. Anyone know what kind of algorithms the rotoscope brush tool is using?

Comment: The algorithm is probably proprietary and most likely insanely complicated. My guess is that someone at Adobe probably based their doctorate thesis on it. Lets just say your iOS app probably isn't going to be able to do that.

Comment: any algorithms that are similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://aeportal.blogspot.ca/2010/04/siggraph-videos-on-roto-brush.html), which contains a couple of video presentations from SIGGRAPH (a computer graphics conference) about the Roto Brush tool. Also take a look at [Jue Wang's paper on Video SnapCut](http://www.juew.org/projects/SnapCut/snapcut.htm). As Damien guessed, object extraction relies on some pretty intense image processing algorithms. You might be able to implement something similar in OpenCV depending on how clever/masochistic you're feeling.

Comment: For info, [this is the SIGGRAPH paper](http://yuwing.kaist.ac.kr/courses/CS770../reading/VideoSnapCut.pdf) that describes the technique.

Comment: Oops. I was busy obsessing over my edit while @RogerRowland beat me to the punch. Still, I suppose it doesn't hurt to have two independent links to the same paper.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is a graph-cut based segmentation algorithm where Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) are trained using color pixels in "local" regions as well as "globally", together with some sort of shape prior.

OpenCV has a "cheap hack" [implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html) of the "GrabCut" paper where the user specifies a bounding box around the object he wish to segment. Typically, using just the bounding box will not give good results. You will need the user to specify the "foreground" and "background" pixels (as is done in Adobe's Rotoscoping tool) to help the algorithm build foreground and background color models (in this case GMMs) so that it will know what are the typical colors in the foreground object you wish to segment, and those for the background that you want to leave out.

A basic graph-cut implementation can be found on this [blog](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/05/05/bust-out-your-own-graphcut-based-image-segmentation-with-opencv-w-code/). You can probably start from there and experiment with different ways to compute the cost terms to get better results.

Lastly, the "soften" the edges, a cheap hack is to blur the binary mask to obtain a mask with values between 0 and 1. Then recomposite your image using the mask i.e. `c[i][j] = mask[i][j] * fgd[i][j] + (1 - mask[i][j]) * bgd[i][j]`, where you are blending the foreground you segmented (fgd), with a new background image (bgd) using the mask values as blending weights.